# Why custom filter is not running in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-filters

Below is my custom filter.

```
app.filter('inputFilter', function () {
return function (str) {
    var output;

    if (str != "" && str != null && isNaN(str)) {
        output = str.trim().toLowerCase();

        return output;
    }
    else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <form method="post" name="loginForm" class="form-group" novalidate>
    <input type="email"  name="username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" required /> 
     {{ user.username | inputFilter }} <!--this line is just for test purpose-->
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" ng-click="login(user)" />

 </form>
```

In this real scenario, filter is not executing.

However, when for testing purpose I flip my html as:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" class="form-control" /> <br/>

    {{ username | inputFilter }}
```

It filters the input string.

My requirement is :

- This is login form, so when user submits his username I want to filter the input & then pass to controller (*I agree there are more simple way to do but I want to do it using filter*)

How do I run filter for my requirement.

Comment: Do you expect filter to modify the value stored in `user.username`?

Comment: @raina77ow, yes not stored, this is login form, so when user submits his username I want to filter the input & then pass to controller

Comment: But it doesn't work this way. Quoting the docs: `Filters are just functions which transform input to an output`. The best you can do is using filter in a getter for that field.

Comment: @raina77ow, "_The best you can do is using filter in a getter for that field_" Sorry!! I didn't get your this point. Can you please add snippet??

Comment: @raina77ow, Custom Filter is filtering the input if I pass simple ng-model but if I pass as _user.username_ , then it doesn't so what's causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you using `type="email"` in the input field , if only email is valid then the value gonna assign to ng-model variable. That's why only for valid email filter would work.

if `type="text"` then for every character you type model gonna change and filter will get executed

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.user =  {};
})
.filter('inputFilter', function () {
  return function (str) { 
    var output;

    if (str != "" && str != null && isNaN(str)) {
        output = str.trim().toLowerCase();

        return output;
    }
    else {
        return str;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <form method="post" name="loginForm" class="form-group" novalidate>
    <input type="email"  name="username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" required /> 
     {{ user.username | inputFilter }}
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"               ng-click="login(user)" />

 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes.Correct,Thankssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your filter.

The reason you thought your filter is not working is because you've used input `type="email"` in which ng-model will only update when the value is valid.

and in testing case it is working because you've used `type="text"` which will automatically updates.

See the demo.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .filter('inputFilter', inputFilter);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.login = function(usr) {
    alert(usr);
  };
  $scope.user = {
    username: 'ABC@xyz.com',
    name: 'ANYthing'
  };

}


function inputFilter() {
  return function(str) {
    var output;

    if (str != "" && str != null && isNaN(str)) {
      output = str.trim().toLowerCase();

      return output;
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <form method="post" name="loginForm" class="form-group" novalidate>
    <div style="border:1px solid"><input type="email" name="username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" required />
      <p>email:</p>
      <p>value: {{ user.username }}</p>
      <p>filter: {{ user.username | inputFilter }}</p>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid">
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" required />
      <p>text:</p>
      <p>value: {{ user.name }}</p>
      <p>filter: {{ user.name | inputFilter }}</p>
    </div>
    <!--this line is just for test purpose-->
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" ng-click="login(user)" />

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh.missed this... Great got it.. Thanksssssssssssssssssss